# Specify project for dependency:copy-dependencies?

Tags: maven, dependencies

[dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) copies the dependencies of the **current** project into some path. How do I copy the dependencies of **other** projects (not the current one) into some path?

**UPDATE**: I doesn't help to declare the other projects as a dependency of the current one because I need to copy each project's dependencies into a separate directory. Declaring them as a dependency on the current project would copy all the dependencies into the same directory, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Call mvn with the parameter -f and the path to the pom of that other project (mvn -f /path/to/pom.xml dependency:copy-dependencies).

Edited from comment:
Then you have to specify that project as a dependency of your first project. Otherwise it wouldn't work (as i read your description, it is a dependency, otherwise i couldn't think of a reason, why i would want that).

Comment: I need to specify the project programmatically (inside the POM file) not from command-line.

Comment: Then you have to specify that project as a dependency of your first project. Otherwise it wouldn't work (as i read your description, it is a dependency, otherwise i couldn't think of a reason, why i would want that).

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain why I can't declare the project as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what are the dependencies of the *other* project (which you can know by examining the pom), you can use the [dependency:copy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) goal specifying the list of `artifacts` that you want to copy.  A few examples are available [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do this too - currently I'm copying dependencies in the sub projects, and then the installer project copies those to its specific subdirectories of target/ by relative path. Dirty hack that requires everything to be in one place. Would be much nicer to be able to copy the dependencies of a dependency.